# Responsive canvas Intel XDK

Tags: android, android-canvas, intel-xdk

I do not work with intel XDK long. I'm making a game and I want the canvas was stretched across the screen on any phone. I tried this

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

In the emulator, it was fine. But on my Android (Nexus 7 G) was only the page background. Canvas disappeared!

Comment: can you share some sample code that can be used to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/73740/intel-xdk-responsive-canvas/

Comment: that link does not work

Comment: So sorry here - http://snipplr.com/view/73741/canvas/

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing canvas inside after DeviceReady is fired, the width and height may not be initialized before the intel.xdk.device.ready is fired.

Here is the modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); margin:0; padding:0;  }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        html, body { background-color:red; color:black; width:100%; height:100%;}
        canvas{background-color: #f00; position: relative; display:block;}
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
            initCanvas();
            //hide splash screen
            intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);

        function initCanvas(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;        
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The result is still the same. The emulator is without errors, but when I run it on the device goes to see only the background and the canvas not. I will try more devices. But Thanks!

Comment: try printing canvas width and height

Comment: Specify printing canvas please.

Comment: add alert and check values: alert(canvas.width +","+ canvas.height);

Answer (score 0):

With Intel XDK, having the `<canvas id="game"></canvas>` is optional, you can access the canvas object directly via `intel.xdk.canvas`.

Moreover, the canvas is **always fullscreen**, you don't need to stretch it yourself.

So, your problem might be related to something else, and you have to show us a sample of your code so we can help you.

Comment: Or first Answer from krisrak.

Comment: I saw this snippet and there's nothing wrong with it, as I said there's no need to implicitly set the canvas size. How exactly is your game not fullscreen?

Comment: The emulator is without errors, but when I run it on the device goes to see only the background and the canvas not. I have android 4.4 and new XDK.

Comment: Ok, can you post an example of your code (that's drawing on canvas) so I can run it & see for myself.

Comment: I got nothing, just doing canvas.